# Why does the following code for switching the visibility of two containers not work and what is the correct way of doing it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am trying to make a button that makes a box visible or invisible depending on the state of another box. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function switchContainers():void {
                if ((screen1.visible = false) && (screen2.visible = true)) {
                    screen2.visible = false;
                    screen2.includeInLayout = false;
                    screen1.visible = true;
                    screen1.includeInLayout = true;
                } else {
                    screen1.visible = false;
                    screen1.includeInLayout = false;
                    screen2.visible = true;
                    screen2.includeInLayout = true;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:SkinnableContainer id="screen1" width="100%" height="80%" backgroundColor="red" visible="false" includeInLayout="false" />
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="screen2" width="100%" height="80%"  backgroundColor="blue" visible="true" includeInLayout="true" />
    <s:Button top="5" left="5" label="Switch containers" click="switchContainers()"/>

</s:Application>
```

Whenever I click the button, nothing happens. I only get to see the blue container. Why doesn't this work?

The ultimate aim of this exercise is to get to display different "screens" in an application (a login screen, a menu screen, etc.) without resorting to ViewStack (I'm trying to use exclusively Spark components). What is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: You forgot the argument MouseEvent in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your conditional statement, you're using an [assignment operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#assignment) (`=`) instead of an [equality operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality) (`==`) when evaluating visibility of screens.

```
if ((screen1.visible = false) && (screen2.visible = true)) {}
```

Change this to an equality expression:

```
if ((screen1.visible == false) && (screen2.visible == true)) {}
```

Another method to accomplish this is to use Flex state system, in which you would define states of `screen1` and `screen2`:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="screen1"/>
    <s:State name="screen2"/>
</s:states>
```

Use the `includeIn` property to include a component:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer id="screen1" includeIn="screen1" />
<s:SkinnableContainer id="screen2" includeIn="screen2" />
```

Then, change state using the `changeState` property:

```
currentState = "screen2";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition, you use the `operator =` (assignment) which assigns a value to a variable, instead of the `operator ==` (equality) which tests two expressions for equality. Your condition should be written like this :

```
if ((screen1.visible == false) && (screen2.visible == true)) {}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why is it mandatory for functions triggered by events to have the event as an argument, even if it's not used to process the output?

Comment: @Laura - AS3 includes a new event model based on the Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Events Specification. This new version of ActionScript introduces a single event handler that replaces the various mechanisms of the previous versions of the language.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is incorrect - it's only mandatory if written within a script block or in a traditional class whereby you are assigning the listener directly via addEventListener.

mxml is a 3rd layer abstraction, where the compiler takes your code and wraps that in an auto-generated AS Class. In this exact case if you were to look at the keep-generated, you would see the equivalent of: clickHander_194983105212 where this calls your internal method - so that passing the argument is optional.

Comment: @Mike Petty - Thanks for that precision.